# simple automatic form builder for POCO or other classes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have lots of POCOs for which I need forms. My main work is currently to copy and paste the ViewModel and View and edit to build all these forms. It is every time the same procedure.

While programming php with symfony I'm able the generate easily a form with validation and so on:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html

Now I want to do the same with WPF. I'm using wpf4 with the MVVM Light Toolkit

I generate the POCO classes from my modell via entity framework

Comment: Take a look at [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I'm searching for a more "ready-to-use" practise. I think there are lots of characteristics which I don't expect so this would cost more time than I save

Comment: http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/